# List of VBA Excel functions that can be used in in MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Where can I find a list of VBA Excel functions and references such as `.sheet`, `.insert` etc. that can be used in MS Access 2003? I'm opening an Excel sheet from MS Access and would like to format the sheet. I'd like to know what commands/functions are available for formatting.

Is there a reference for this online? Something that can provide information on tasks like adding gridlines, formatting currency, etc.

Comment: Huh? Access isn't Excel.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm openning an excel sheet from MSaccess and would like to format the sheet. I'd like to know what commands/functions are available for formatting. Is there a reference for this online? Such as adding gridlines, formatting currency etc Thanks!

Comment: Not explicit in the answers here, but once you've added a reference to Excel (or even without it, if you use late binding), then your Access VBA can use the same set of objects/methods available in Excel VBA.  It's not a subset.

Comment: You don't need to add a reference to use Excel functionality -- it can be done with late binding (and probably should be, actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you wish to access the functionality of Excel through Access by using the Excel library? Create a reference and either use the object browser or intellisense to explore Excel.WorksheetFunction.

EDIT Re Comment

You can also explore the Excel libraries for formating and so forth, once the reference to the library is added.

Comment: Go into the Visual Basic editor in your Access program, go to Tools->References, and then check "Microsoft Excel #.## Object Library." (The #.## will differ depending on which version of Excel you have.) Now you can create an Excel object within your functions like so: `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application : Set xlApp = New Excel.Application`. When you put a period (.) after xlApp, you will now see the Intellisense drop-down which shows every property and method available to you from the Application object.

Comment: ... furthermore, once you have the reference you can then go to View->Object Browser in the VB editor. In the top drop-down box, it should say "<All Libraries>". Change this to Excel, and then you can see all of the Excel objects available to you.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: My intellisense wasn't working because I was using Dynamic Late Binding. I had to manually add the Excel Object Library Reference for intellisense to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is the reason I used Late Binding.